# Hausdorff-Young / Restriction Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\lambda$ denote Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. The Hausdoff-Young inequality is that 
$$
\| \widehat{f} \|_{L^{q}(\lambda)} \leq \| f \|_{L^{p}(\lambda)}.
$$
when $1 \leq p \leq 2$ and $q=p'$.

Given a Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$, the Fourier restriction inequality is 
$$
\| \widehat{f} \|_{L^{q}(\mu)} \leq \| f \|_{L^{p}(\lambda)}.
$$
The Fourier restriction problem asks for which $p$, $q$, and $\mu$ this inequality holds.

Suppose $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$.

If $\mu$ has bounded (or $L^{\infty}$) density, then the restriction inequality holds with $1 \leq p \leq 2$ and $q=p'$ by Holder's inequality and Hausdorff-Young. Moreover, if the support of the density has finite Lebesgue measure, then $q \leq p'$ is also valid.

What happens to the restriction inequality if $\mu$ does not have bounded density?

Comment: The the density of $\mu$ is in some $L^r_{\text{loc}}$, then Holder's inequality is basically the best you can do there; the right hand side will be a sum of $L^p$ and $L^{s}$ where $s$ is determined by $r$ and Hausdorff Young.  You can check that by a scaling argument.

Comment: @WillieWong Could you flesh this out a bit more? Where does the sum come from?

Comment: The sum comes from the example in the back of my mind (sorry for not being clear) when $\mu$ has a density that can be decomposed as the sum of a $L^r$ function and a $L^\infty$ function. (If the density is not bounded near $\infty$ then you expect to lose derivatives on the physical side and cannot generally expect the sort of restriction inequality you want to hold; so when I see your question I think of the case where the density is bounded outside a compact set and within the compact set is only $L^r$.)

Comment: @WillieWong How can I see the inequality fails if the density is unbounded near infinity?

Comment: 1. Let $K$ be any compact set, on the complement $\mathbb{R}^d \setminus K$, there are not mutual inclusions between $L^p$ and $L^q$ for $p\neq q$. 2. Let $h:\mathbb{R}^d \setminus K \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with $\inf h > M > 0$. Then the mapping $f\mapsto hf$ for $f\in L^p$ is either unbounded, or has operator norm at least $M$. 3. Try to prove the statement for the case the density of $\mu$ is $(1 + |x|^2)^\sigma$ for $\sigma > 0$. The general case follows not too more difficultly.

Comment: @WillieWong: Correct me if I'm wrong. I assume you are talking about the map $T: f \mapsto hf$ as map from $L^p$ to $L^q$. . The operator norm $\|T\|$ satisfies $\|T\|^q = \sup\{ \int |fh|^q : \|f \|_p = 1\}$. I see that $\int |fh|^q \geq \int_K |fh|^q + M^q \int_{K^c} |f|^q$. What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: @WillieWong When $\mu$ ha density $g$, I know the restriction inequality is equivalent to $\|   \widehat{f} g^{1/q} \|_q \leq \| f \|_{p}$. How should I connect this with the blueprint you have given?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have neither the time nor energy to hold your hand through every single step of the argument. (I really suggest you discuss this with your tutor or professor, since from your comments you are missing some very basic techniques in analysis.) So one last-ditch effort: to prove an inequality $\|Tf\|_{L^q} \leq C \|f\|_{L^p}$ is false, the usual way is to construct a sequence $f_i$ such that $\|f_i\|_{L^p} = 1$ and $\|Tf_i\|_{L^q} \nearrow \infty$. So see if you can construct such an $f_i$ using exactly the ingredients that I gave above.

Comment: To make it even more explicit: take $f_i$ to be "frequency translations" of one fixed $f_0$ which has compact support in frequency space.